# How to update android app without uninstalled from device

Tags: android, apk

when i try to **update version** in my android app to **own site**. The problem will be occured during the installation. that's

> App not installed
>
> An Existing package by the same name with a conflicting is already
>   installed.

Can any one help how to download updated app without uninstall.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you sign apk with same keystore?

Comment: You cannot to that, if you have signed with different `key`

Comment: yes i have tried sign apk with same and different keystore also but not worked

Comment: @VenomVendor i tried different key but not working

Comment: @Android : Is the version on your device a debug version and the update a release version (or the other way around)? You can't update debug -> release or release -> debug.

Comment: @Squonk how to do that can u explain clearly?

Comment: @Android : You haven't answered my question. If you have a debug version on your device and want to install a release version you *MUST* uninstall the debug version first. The same applies if the version on the device is a release version and you want to install a debug version. There is no way around this - debug and release apps are signed with different keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change both

```
android:versionCode="4"
android:versionName="1.0.4" 

android:versionCode is a integer, eveny update increment by 1
android:versionName can any string
```

and you use same Keystore

Comment: yes i increament the version code also but not working

Comment: then the problem cloud be with Keystore.
check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959890/android-app-not-install-an-existing-package-by-the-same-name-with-a-conflicting

Answer (score -1):

**If your installing from your own site, don't increment the version code and name of new apk your uploading, use the same code and name of already existing apk, it will replace the existing one so no need to uninstall the app.**

Try by enabling the "install app from unknown source" in device settings

Best way to do Even if your using the app for internal purpose you can sign the app using live keystore(not debug keystore) and upload it in your own site.

Another way to avoid getting your scenario:

If you want only some particular users to download the app that is the reason if you have hosted your app in your own site means, google provides an option to do this for testers where you can add their email in alpha testing or beta testing so that whenever you upload an apk to playstore those users who you have added will be notified and can update the app without uninstalling the existing(this wont be visible to all users who you have not added).