# Android App not start after click

Tags: android

After i click my app, my app can't start.

There is the log print by system, i note there is a line say package not found in list.
My phone is XiaoMi and this problem is less show in nexus5.
[image: The log print by system]
Dose any one know what the problem is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959890/android-app-not-install-an-existing-package-by-the-same-name-with-a-conflicting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have installed the app in the device sometime before with a different build/signature. since the app has the same package name (i.e com.example.*), the android OS is not able to install the newer version with different signature. Please delete the older version and try running it again. This should help!

Comment: I uninstall the old version and install new one, but the problem is always here.

Comment: Please check if there are provisions for multiple profiles on ur device (i.e app might be uninstalled for the current user and not the other ones). So please do check in settings->apps and find if ur app is shown (possibly last in the list). Try uninstalling for all users  and run the app :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i think it was cause i set my activity as Home. It's really strange. When i remove it, this problem not show again