# App not installed. An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature. Two app with same prefix package name

Tags: android

I developed application with "com.sober.myapp1" package name. When I finished application , I create signed apk and install on my phone. After a while I developed another application with "com.sober.myapp2" but when I create signed apk for this app I get "App not installed. An existing ...". So I can't have both application installed on my phone. If I have myapp1 I can't install myapp2. I also use same key for signing my apps. What is problem really ?
please pay attention. I haven't one application with debug and release apk. I have two completely different application.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959890/android-app-not-install-an-existing-package-by-the-same-name-with-a-conflicting. Have you built both apps in release mode?

Comment: please read issue carefully. I haven't one application with debug and release key. I have two completely different app with same prefix package name.

Comment: Yes. I have built both app in release mode