# Updated Android app built with Codename One instead of Android Studio

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, codenameone

I built an Android app natively in Android Studio. Now that I want to port it to iOS, I have started working with Codename One. In order to keep the code and any subsequent changes easier to maintain, I want to update my earlier Android version of the app with the one I'm building now with Codename One, which will then be my new release version.

I have a few questions:

1. If I have the Keystore certificate of the Android app I built natively in Android Studio and use it in my Codename One app, will it update my first app? I saw [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19960210/5095571) but want to verify if it'll work in this case.
2. If I can do this update, how can I preserve any **sqlite data** from the 1st version of the app after updating to the app I built with Codename One?
3. Similar to question 2, how can I preserve any directories with **app data** (folders containing PDfs and images) when I upgrade? I stored data locally within the app, hidden to any Android file explorer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The keystore should work fine if it doesn't it will fail during the build or won't generate a release version
- You need to test this, it depends on "where" you stored the sqlite data. Codename One isn't as flexible in terms of locations where you can store SQLite and you might need to use the `FileSystemStorage` API to move it. There is discussion on "shipping a database" with your app in the developer guide that you can reference to understand how to place the SQLite database in a specific location.
- They might be within `FileSystemStorage` but you might want to migrate that to `Storage` to increase portability. Notice that directory hierarchies aren't as portable so we removed support for them in the `Storage` API