# App not installed. An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature

Tags: android, google-play, release

I have published a release build with release signature in the play store. Now I have to publish an update build so increased versionCode and versionName and used same release signature to create signed apk. I thought to test update feature manually before uploading apk in the play store but it throwing error

```
App not installed. An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature
```

Google play is accepting same build, I have uploaded same build in the beta version and it's being update.

This seems strange things to me as earlier I have tested update manually many times

I would really appreciate if anyone provide clarity on this.

Thanks in Advance.

**Edit**
For Manual Update test, Using below steps

1. Installed application from google play
2. Creating a release build with versionCode and versionName upgradation with same signing key used for previous version
3. puting apk inside sdcard and trying to install/directly installing apk from Android studio.

The strange thing is same apk is being uploaded for update in google play and I'm able to update my application.

I would like to know is there any security added in latest version. I'm using **SDK 26**. Why manual update showing signature conflict error?

Comment: How are you installing the new version of app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959890/android-app-not-install-an-existing-package-by-the-same-name-with-a-conflicting

Comment: @Sagar for manual  update test, saving same apk in sdcard  and just clicking on this to check update, same apk  has been published in beta and it's being updated.

Comment: It seems that in the new Google Play system when you upload an app they created a new keystore specifically for Google Play and embed that keystore to the APK. So the APK from Google Play and your created release APK is using different keystore. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have test build installed in your device. Uninstall previous build and try installing Release APK.

Comment: It's not test build in my device installed app from play store.

Answer (score 0):

Since the app has been already installed, trying to install it from SD card won't trigger update usecase. It will simply try to install and will fail because the app is already installed.

You can use `adb` command to simulate the scenario.

Simply use command `adb install -r <apkname>.apk` from command prompt.

Comment: I have not tried this command but tried installing from android studio too. it gets failed.

Comment: @Dilip Just try out this command

Comment: getting this error Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package <package name> signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]

Comment: @Dilip looks like you are installing apk signed with different signature. Are you sure you are building release apk correctly? or you are trying to install debug version?

Comment: it's release apk bcz with same signature google play is accepting build. I have uploaded build in beta and i can test update there

Comment: @Dilip I mean the one installed on your phone. Are you sure, its signed with correct signature and is not an debug version?

Comment: yeah @Sagar becase have installed application from play store. Little strange behavior. is there any security change in sdk 26?

Comment: @Dilip AFAIK, no changes. Its quite strange. Update this information in your question so that someone else doesn't recommend the same