# How to Upgrade APK with Install Intent

Tags: android, apk

I need to upgrade an APK that is distributed outside of Play Store. I was able to download the new APK and launched the install with this intent

```
    private void startInstall(File appApkFile) {
    if (appApkFile.exists()) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", appApkFile);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
            intent.setData(apkUri);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else {
            Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(appApkFile);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The install launches however because the app already exists on the device the install fails with the error message that "the package conflicts with an existing package by the same name"

Would anyone know how to pass the upgrade flag to the Install Intent action?

[image: APK Installed Failed]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959890/android-app-not-install-an-existing-package-by-the-same-name-with-a-conflicting

Comment: make sure it is signed with same keystore as the original app. Also probably it has to increase version_code.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko has answered your question correctly. You need to upgrade version number and sign using the same keystore.

Answer (score 1):

please use signed apk  file in both debug and release version

Comment: that was the issue. Thanks