# Android application installing only once

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, mobile-application

I have created an android application. When I installed the apk file for the first time in my mobile it has been installed successfully. But When I try to uninstall it and reinstall the same app then it is not installing saying "`app can not be installed`"

But when I try to install the same app in another mobile for the first time then it installed and when I uninstall it and tried to install there is the same problem, saying "`app can not be installed`"

It means the app only install once in one device. Why?
I want the app to install and uninstall multiple times as normal `.apk` installation.

Please guide me.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of similar issues already answered to on this site.

['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android)

[Android App Not Install. An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959890/android-app-not-install-an-existing-package-by-the-same-name-with-a-conflicting)

> The problem is the keys that have been used to sign the APKs, by default if you are running directly from your IDE and opening your Emulator, the APK installed in the Emulator is signed with your debug-key(usually installed in ~/.android/debug.keystore), so if the previous APK was signed with a different key other than the one you are currently using you will always get the signatures conflict, in order to fix it, make sure you are using the very same key to sign both APKs, even if the previous APK was signed with a debug-key from another SDK, the keys will definitely be different.

I had the same problem earlier this year and to me signing my APK did the job. Please refer to [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) in order to do this.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is with your device kind check the same on other device
or the cache is not clearing after you uninstall the 
check the android folder if there is an folder related to your app
delete if you found

Comment: I checked entire Android folder but nothing related and i deleted playstore cashe. But still the same problem.